# How to get Mac's terminal to use Brew's PHP version?

Tags: php, macos, terminal, homebrew

I'm currently trying to get PHP 7.1 on my mac. I followed this guide and successfully installed and linked php71 https://developerjack.com/blog/2016/08/26/Installing-PHP71-with-homebrew/

However, when running php -v from the terminal (after restarting computer, after running source bashprofile etc.), I still get PHP 5.6.30 (cli). Is there a way to get the terminal to use brews install instead of the version that comes with mac?

Comment: make `/usr/local/bin` come first in your path (do that in .bashrc).

Comment: read about **[bash_profile vs bashrc](https://www.google.ca/search?q=bash_profile+vs+bashrc&oq=bash_provile+vs+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5015j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)** to be certain that you attain your ultimate objective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Various ways:

- make a softlink from your php location to `/usr/local/bin` e.g. `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/php /usr/local/bin/php` and make sure `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in your path variable.
- make an alias in `.bash_profile` (restart your terminal) `alias php = /yourpath`

Comment: Thanks. I switched my .bash_profile up to check usr/local/bin before usr/bin and that did the trick. I'm not certain that that's the best way to do it, but it probably makes sense to do the most specific things first.